# 各処理の名称について質問です

Tags: 専門用語

以下の項目について、用語としてどう伝えるのが適切が質問です。
曖昧にしてきたところがあり、これを機に正しく認識させたいです。

1.phpのようにひとつの実行プログラムで完結する仕組みの名称
手続き型言語という呼び方だと明らかにおかしいので、困っています。
一挙完結型？一般的にはどのように呼ぶのが適切なのか。

2.フレームで管理する処理の名称
1フレーム、2フレーム、3フレーム・・・でそれぞれ処理をすることを指します。
フレーム間処理？

お手数をおかけいたしますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

追記

**シングルスレッド、マルチスレッド**あたりがニュアンス的に近いですが、2をマルチスレッドというのが若干違和感がある、と考えています。

追記

要領得てないかつ、質問の意図が伝わってないことと、また一部有意義な意見が出たので整理しなおします。

1に関してはひとつの実行スクリプトで完結することの名称の質問です。
2に関しては「フレーム毎に実行される処理」の名称です。

1と2の関係性についてはそこまで深いわけではないですが、1は一般的にはWebアプリケーション、2はゲームプログラミングなどでよく見かけられるものになります。

範囲が広い、というコメントがありましたが**それらの処理の総称**なので狭い領域での話ではありません。
今回、Webでの処理とゲームなどで使われるフレーム間の処理それぞれの名称をなんと呼称すべきか、というところが質問です。
(Web開発の経験しかない場合は2がイメージしづらいかもしれません、正しい名称を把握してないのでいまいち要領得ない質問の仕方になっています)

Comment: その二つの概念は何か関連しているのでしょうか。どちらもphp絡みとか、Webアプリケーション絡みとか。あまり関連性がないのであれば、それぞれ別の質問に分けてもいいかもしれません。

Comment: その上で、「フレーム」についてもう少し説明していただけませんか？例えば[Wikipediaで見ると色々な意味が書かれていますが](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0)、このいずれかに該当するものでしょうか。あるいはフレームの具体例を挙げていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: @unarist さん　
コメントありがとうございます。

いずれもPHP絡みではなく、全体的な話です。
Webに限らず、プログラミングの分野です。
また、「フレーム」についてはゲームプログラミングなどでよく使われる「フレームごとに処理する」といったときのフレームです。
ビデオのコマなどのフレームとニュアンス的には似ているかと思います。

また今回の質問は1と2がそれぞれ対の位置にいると考えてるからこそ1つの質問であげさせていただいています。

Comment: 「手続き型言語」はプログラミング言語自体の設計思想を説明しているのに対して、質問文の1および2で問われているのはプログラムの動作するフレームワークがどのような設計であるかで、直接の関係はないように思われます。

Comment: どちらかというとデザインパターンの区分に近いような。Q2だと [Sequencing Patterns · Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/sequencing-patterns.html) というような分類をしている方がいるようです

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考になります！たしかにデザインパターンの区分のほうがしっくりくるところはありますね・・・。

Comment: あまりに対象領域が広すぎて、まともに回答のしようがない質問に見えます。Q1とQ2には関連性や、なんらかのつながりがあるのでしょうか？またQ2のフレームは映像フレーム(video frame)を指しているようですが、対象領域としてはゲームプログラミングなどを想定していますか？

Comment: なおさっき紹介したURL先の内容は和訳本としても出版されているようです。[Game Programming Patterns - 達人出版会](http://tatsu-zine.com/books/game-programming-patterns)

Comment: 追加情報ありがとうございます！

Comment: 「対の位置にいる」とありますが、ではPCやスマートフォン上で動くGUIアプリケーションは対比させる必要はないのでしょうか。あるいは1に属するのでしょうか。

Comment: インタプリタ言語(ないしスクリプト)における1関数(1処理？)の実行単位みたいな話でしょうか？？？

Comment: @unarist さん
質問的にはGUIアプリケーションは1側に属すると思っています。
(もしかしたらちょっとちがう可能性はあります。。。)

Comment: @harry0000 さん
求めている答え的には「インタプリタ言語」のほうが限りなく近い気がしますが、
求めている答えとしては実行単位になりますね。
(その処理の総称を今回求めているところになりますので)

Comment: 1行単位であれば、`ステップ`な気はします(デバッグでいう`ステップ`実行など)。その他の単位の名称については専門用語に明るくない為ちょっとわかりません。`(コール)スタック`は少し違うような気もしますし。

Comment: `ステートレス`と`ステートフル`とか、`モードレス`と`モーダル`とか。`同期`と`非同期`。普通の`逐次的`なコード（データドリブンとは言いたくないけど）か`イベントドリブン`か。まぁ幅の広い話ですね。GUIならまず間違いなくイベントドリブン。

Comment: コメント欄でディスカッションしないでください。ディスカッションがしたいならチャットでどうぞ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もとの定義をかなり広義に解釈することになるかもしれませんが、以下の様な用語ではいかがでしょうか。

1. [バッチ処理](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86)、もしくは[命令型プログラミング](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%91%BD%E4%BB%A4%E5%9E%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0)
2. イベントドリブン、もしくは[イベント駆動型プログラミング](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E9%A7%86%E5%8B%95%E5%9E%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0)

リンク先はいずれもWikipediaです。

Comment: 説明する際にそのワードだと十分要件満たせそうです！
ありがとうございます！